# Could someone please explain why my buttons and links jump and shake left and right?

Tags: html, button, navigation, responsive-design

I have a problem whenever I want a button to position or links it seems to JUMP left or right and becomes shaky when I hover over it.

I tried to include some print screens but my reputation here is not high enough. 
Cheers,
Ted

check my site to see what I mean. hiretednow.com thanks

1. my navigation buttons jump to the right when I hover over them:

   HOME

   ```
         <li><a href="#services">Expertise | Skills</a></li>
         <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">About TED</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Get In Touch</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
     </div>
     </div>
   ```
2. the same thing happens with certain links that I have created. I checked in Jfiddle and it seems to work fine, perhaps it could be an issue with the Browsers or Javascript?
3. To position buttons or p style text  I use style position...but perhaps someone could explain me how I can do this in CSS instead of HTML as on the mobile phone they don't resize.

EXAMPLES:

img src="assets/img/map.jpg" style="position: absolute; bottom: 340px; right: 140px;"/

p style="position: absolute; bottom: 585px; right: 185px;"/>I AM CURRENTLY LOCATED IN LONDON, UK

a href="https://twitter.com/jus_ted" target="_blank">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  In your main.css file you have a:hover with margin-right: 600px; which is causing them to jump around.

2) I would imagine that the reason it only happens with some links and not all is the style gets trumped through specificity elsewhere in your CSS. (To learn more about CSS specificity have a google about or try using this which helped me: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html)

3) I would need more information about what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I noticed you are using Twitter Bootstrap. You can use pull-left and pull-right classes (experiment with where you put them to see different results) and you can also utilise the grid system by including new  and adjusting  widths. If you haven't already, check out the Bootstrap documentation on their grid system [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

Comment: Hi Rhys, yes I am quite a newbie to CSS. I use my site to learn along the way, perhaps I should have started from the basics, but so far I have managed. What I want to achieve is that my social media buttons are now positioned through p style, which is the whole reason why my top menu navigation also started to jump when you move over them. I want my social media link to respond to the responsive theme, but when viewing my site on a mobile phone you can exactly see that almost the whole side does respond quite well, except certain links that are using the p style.

Comment: Thanks Rhys. I would appreciate your advice. Just let me know if you require more information on the code.

Comment: :) Rhys amazing. I changed the 600px margin right in my main.css file to 0px now it doesn't jump !!! Perhaps by accident I have added 600px. Ok this was my main issue. If you can give me advice how to my footerwrap | social media section can be responsive like the rest of the side I owe you a beer haha. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem, I'm sure you'll start getting used to it soon enough. The reason your social links are moving over is because you've set a fixed margin on the images, and fixed margins don't mix well with a responsive site :D

You should aim to use %, em and ex units instead of px (see link <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp">here.</a>

Also, bootstrap will handle the resizing for you if you set it up right.What you need to do is use <div class="row"> inside your container, which will give you a full width block.

Comment: Then inside that row you can set up multiple <div class="spanX"> which will take care of horizontal spacing. So you can have 3 <div class="span4"> which will divide your space into thirds (the full width of the grid is 12). You can also have empty spans to provide space, so for example if you wanted to have 50% of your space centred in the middle of the screen, you could have <div class="span3"></div><div class="span6"></div> and then put your content in the span6.

Comment: So what you need to do is the container inside footerwrap, have 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">congratulations</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">First of all...</div>
        <div class="span4">social links</div>
        <div class="span4">map</div>
    </div>

You can then start using margin-top: instead of lots of <br> tags to space your content vertically. Also, I would recommend you start putting your CSS into classes, as it is a lot easier when it comes to editing (and its considered best practice afaik).

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for your advice. Really appreciate it ! Will let you know how it will progress.